# Youtube video in Android WebView not playing in real device

Tags: android, webview, youtube, android-emulator

I'm developing an app that shows html content grabbed from a JSON in a WebView, the html contains a few words and an embedded youtube video.
The HTML content is showed correctly, but the Youtube video isn't, it just shows a black box where the video should be.
This problem does not exists if I run my app on the emulator (Nexus 5X API 24) but in my real device (Samsung API 17) it doesn't work.
This is my webview configuration (I also added the hardware accelerated option in the manifest)

```
mWebView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

When I run the app on the real device it throws an exception:

```
E/Web Console: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL https://www.youtube.com/embed/blabla. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

I can't find a solution for this problem, every tutorial I find does the same things that I do

Comment: try using `https://www.youtube.com` as a base URL. The error says that you should point a base URL, as for me

Comment: Ok the app is not throwing the exception anoymore if I add the base url, but still no video :( can't figure out why it works on the emulator

Comment: I created a new emulator with API 17, and the problem persists.
So it should be something with older version of Android